# Make a permanet arg in js like angular $scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have seen permanent arguments in AngularJS like $scope

```
var app = angular.module("app",[]);
app.conntroller("ctrl",function($scope){
    $scope.name = "Angular JS";
});
```

And when "$scope" is renamed to another text like 'scope' and it does not work. But my question is not about angular js. My question is: How do I make a function to parse permanent argument in js?

Comment: $scope is being passed in using Angularjs's custom [Dependency Injection](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di) system. Are you asking how you can create a dependency injection system?

Comment: yes............

Comment: That's a really big topic...

Comment: can you tell me a good link to learn that...?

Comment: I linked [angularjs's documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di) in my first comment. There's also [this youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0X1Ns2NRfks) introducing the basics of dependency injection.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because objects are passed to function by reference unlike primitive variables which are passed by value.

```
function func(obj){
obj.hello="Hello world";
};
var myObj={};
func(myObj);
console.log(myObj.hello);
// outputs hello world
```

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this by using @Injection

and another way to achieve the same for the project go with task runners like **gulp or grunt**

```js
var app = angular.module('testApp',[]);
app.controller('testCtrl',['$scope',function(scope){
    scope.temp="Angular Js";
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="testCtrl" class="">
{{temp}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS has a rather unique dependency injection system, which is probably not going to be very useful to you, but here's how it works:

First, the basic idea is just to pass things into other functions. For example, in the following code, injectHello makes sure that the word hello is passed into whatever function you want.

```js
function greet(greeting) {
    alert(greeting);
}

function injectHello(fxn) {
    fxn('hello');
}

injectHello(greet)
```

In angularjs's injector, instead of the injector always injecting a predefined thing, it looks up what to pass in from a list of all the services/providers/etc that you have created previously. And the way that you tell the injector what you want is with a special $inject property that you add to the function. So it might look something like this:

```js
const services = {
   'helloService': 'hello',
   'salutationsService': 'salutations'
}

function inject(fxn) {
    const key = fxn.$inject[0];
    fxn(services[key]);
}

function greet(greeting) {
    alert(greeting)
}

greet.$inject = ['helloService'];

inject(greet);
```

AngularJS's injector also offers another way to inject things, which only works in non-minified builds. They will do `fxn.toString()`, then parse the string to see what you named your parameters. If they see that you named the parameter `helloService`, then it will pretend that you added `$inject = ['helloService']`, and do the lookup with that.